# Who is notifed when a post is flagged in a private beta?

Tags: support, private-beta

During the private beta users have the option to flag a post (I haven't tried but I assume flagging is functional).  Since it is still private beta the moderators have not been selected yet.  Who gets notified of flagged posts?

Comment: The team are moderators

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Stack Overflow staff (or a subset of) are moderators from the start of a private beta.

Comment: This is correct. Typically, there are 7-10 Moderators from the Stack Overflow staff when the site is created.

Answer (score 7):

The [**"valued associates"**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127098/who-are-stack-overflow-valued-associates) are moderators from the start. Additionally, users with enough rep to have access to the 10k tools can see spam and offensive flags.

Comment: During a private beta, nobody is going to have the rep high enough for access to the moderation tools.  Though the [rep points are lowered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) it takes a bit during the public beta for anyone to get close to the moderation tools at 2K.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff It's 1k for private betas, 2k for public; so it *is* actually quite achievable. We're on day 3 at Aviation, and a few people are almost at mod tools.