# Who are Stack Overflow Valued Associates?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team

I have seen "Stack Overflow Valued Associate" on many user profiles. What does it mean?

Comment: @gdoron Examples: [Jeff](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), [Nick](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver), [Jason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6212/jason-punyon)

Comment: @SachinShekhar you could also click the link you know. [Nick](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-nick-craver/), [Jason](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-hires-in-new-york/) :)

Comment: I don't understand why all of the downvotes. This seems like a reasonable question for people who aren't in on the joke/don't follow every single event re: Stack Exchange. I say this would be a good FAQ.

Comment: @alE - simply clicking on the link would have explained it.

Comment: @AlEverett well, it's mentioned briefly in the [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/152859) faq, maybe better expand it a bit instead of starting new one?

Comment: Over at https://chess.stackexchange.com/ they should rename "pawn" to "valued associate".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are the employees of Stack Exchange inc.

Valued associates get announced on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?s=valued%20associate) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+announcements+community-managers).