# Join me in Welcoming Valued Associates: #945 - Slate - and #948 - Charlotte

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

I’m excited to introduce you to the two newest members of the Community team. [Slate](https://stackexchange.com/users/22246329/) and [Charlotte](https://stackexchange.com/users/22208366/) have joined us as Associate Community Managers. They are joining JNat and Catija on Community Ops and will report to me. Slate and Charlotte will eventually oversee tickets that come through the contact us forms network wide. They will also start getting involved in elections, triaging Meta requests, and other projects that the Ops team are involved with. Here’s a little bit about our newest additions to the team.

**Slate**

Slate is quite familiar with the Stack Exchange Network. She was a founding member of Puzzling, Literature, and Community Building. On Puzzling and Literature, she served as a pro-tempore moderator. On Puzzling, she was later elected as a full moderator. After many years as a moderator on Stack Exchange, she’s now excited to join us as a Community Manager.

At her last job, her focus was in statistics and data science for spaceflight applications. She studied physics and math, and continues to self-study both in her free time. For fun she spends time playing role-playing games, where she and friends gather around a table building worlds and narratives. She also reads quite a bit, fiction and nonfiction alike, and has a passion for understanding how stories are told.

**Charlotte**

Charlotte is also no stranger to SO, having used the site frequently when she was a student. She has been a community empowerer in the Brazilian tech community collaborating with tutorial videos, responding to questions over Twitter and email about how to start a career in tech, programming, or data management. She has a database technologist certification and  experience handling relational databases.

Outside of her passion for data and tech communities, she loves music, especially punk and metal. She’s attended a number of festivals and even got to photograph and interview some of her favorite bands. She loves to chat and get to know different people. She is also addicted to comics and her favorite superhero is Wonder Woman (even though she also loves Marvel). She has a big collection dedicated to the super hero in her house, including a big back tattoo piece of a samurai Wonder Woman with a dragon. She is also part of the comics community, contributing content such as covering the San Diego Comic Con.

Please join us in congratulating Slate and Charlotte on their new roles here!

Comment: You say Slate was a founding member and moderator of puzzling, but their [account on puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75951/slate) has 1 rep. What’s going on here?

Comment: @EkadhSingh Seems reasonable that some employees may want to start with a new account as staff. I don't see it as all that mysterious...

Comment: @EkadhSingh Clearly it's a puzzle for you to solve. I would expect nothing less from a longtime member

Comment: @EkadhSingh The old account has been deleted. It used to be account number 20.

Comment: @EkadhSingh: Somebody wanted to be a [clean Slate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clean_slate) …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Believe it or not, this was an accident. I originally went for a different rock-related username, but it just so happened to sound particularly foul in another language... So I went with the next closest sounding thing, and that was "Slate."

Comment: While I welcome 945 and 948, please also say hello to 946 and 947 from me. They also deserve a great, welcomimg start of their career at SE.

Comment: I thought the "Staff" card was going to stay on the profile page. Discreet it isn't.

Comment: @Slate I hope that doesn't mean you expected a *rocky* start to the new job.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I fully expect it to be a metamorphic time.

Comment: What do the 945 and 948 refer to?

Comment: @SteveBennett I guess it is the inmate ID number ;)  .... more seriously, it is the sequence number of staff hired at SE. Has been a tradition since number 1: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127098/who-are-stack-overflow-valued-associates#comment345044_127098

Comment: While congratulating both of them, I'm curious. Why do answers/comments here not have a time stamp like other SO answers/comments? All of them has the 'yesterday' next to them, but no exact date or time.

Comment: @Sandun that's how all timestamps show up. They show relative time (e.g., "5 hours ago", "yesterday", "2 days ago") for about a week. Then they revert to a date and time.

Comment: OMG SE is run by a rabbit?! So much makes sense now. XD

Comment: Congrats to the new community members, and I must say, that is a solid name choice.

Comment: Congrats and welcome.... Just out of curiosity, are these paid positions or volunteer?

Comment: @JosephDoggie community managers are all paid positions. :)

Comment: @Nate Looks more like a guinea pig instead... :D

Comment: Congratulations, folks.

Answer (score 75):

I know I have been saying this out loud to everyone that I already met, but I just can't say enough how happy I am to be here! This is all very new to me, as I was a Database Administrator before falling from the sky here like an angel.

As someone that have been working in the tech field for so long, Stack Overflow has been my buddy! I can't tell you how many times I got saved from a major problem I had no idea about and someone, somewhere, had the nice gesture on sharing their solution to the community.
So getting to know how Stack Exchange works and all its sites, having that *backstage* feeling is honestly rad!

It is a honor to me to be here today!

What this place represents, the values and the environment are everything I ever looked for to be part of, I can truly feel the sense of community from my amazing team and everyone else I had the pleasure meeting so far.

Stack Exchange really cares about bringing talents, because everyone is so unique and ready to help. There is no recruiters, there is talent hunters! From the marketing, to developers, to sales, to leadership, to the community...

As part of the crew, I promise to always try my best and keep up developing my skills, to grow and help everyone around me grow as well, like beautiful sunflowers reaching to the sun. *(I really tried to be sentimental here, ok? Sorry about that.)*
I will deliver the best results possible, I promise to always expose my ideas to improve this place because I know my opinions matter.

I hope to be here for a very long time to see all the exciting things coming! Seriously, there is so much room for activities here, it's exciting!

I would like to mention everyone in this message, but I will only give a shoutout here to my new partner in crime, Slate, because she is incredible as well and I think we will do real amazing things here!

For now,
Thank y'all for having me! I appreciate all of you.

Comment: Congrats, and best of luck! Instead of "break a leg", should we say "drop a table"? :-)

Comment: Welcome, Charlotte! I look forward to seeing you around! :)

Comment: Bem-vinda e sucesso!

Comment: When do we get to see that tattoo?  I am trying to imagine what "a samurai Wonder Woman" looks like.  If not wanting to reveal your actual skin, do you have the printed copy of the artwork?  (I am not a tattoo enthusiast nor am I a DC enthusiast. How can I see the tattoo without being creepy interweb guy?)

Comment: Maybe we can start a new community for tattoo lovers and I can show? Haha one day when the appropriate time rises I can show this really pretty (and painful) piece of art. ☺️

Comment: @Charlotte https://area51.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @TylerH - let's not say "drop a table".  I'm afraid she'll listen to community advice and give it a shot!  (And I'm not sure if it'll be a db table or a physical table!)

Answer (score 69):

*And lo, the roiling wave of diamonds crashes down upon me...*

Well, maybe not quite that dramatic. Hi readers! I'm Slate. I'll keep this brief, because there's not all too much to say yet.

I'm happy to be back to contributing to Stack Exchange, this time in quite a new capacity. My history with the network spans quite a number of years, but today it becomes my full-time job. That's quite special to me, and I'm grateful to the team for the opportunity to contribute in this way. And, hey, Meta's always been my primary home on Stack, from almost the day I started as a user. I hardly expect that to change now!

I used to have a now-deleted mid-to-high rep account, which some of you probably remember quite well. Probably some of you even accurately remember my account IDs, which is beyond me... to be clear, I don't mind people making these connections - in fact, I expect it! Especially for a lot of the older folks around. For more recent members, don't worry too much about this, though I'm always happy to share history with the curious.

Honestly, I'm much looking forward to catching up with everyone again, and meeting new faces. So, if anyone has questions or just wants to talk, I'm happy to respond here or strike up conversation in any Stack chat.

Comment: You could always drop by [the tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta ) if you want to. Plenty of <strikethrough>people who don’t sleep</strikethrough> great people there

Comment: @EkadhSingh Dropped a hello there! Thanks for the reminder. Forgot people can't ping me if I don't say hi...

Comment: Welcome back! There's a certain... Justice... To this.

Comment: Good to see you around, @Shog9. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: "older folks"?  I'm glad that wasn't pointed at me... :P

Comment: Welcome, Slate! Always good to see more mods from the Stack Exchange network becoming CMs for the company... :)

Comment: why was your old account deleted?

Comment:  Welcome @Slate [World Heritage Site](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2021/jul/28/welsh-slate-landscape-becomes-uks-newest-world-heritage-site)

Comment: @hanshenrik I voluntarily removed them - I wanted to take a break from SE, and I figured if I'd ever come back, it'd be under new terms anyway. I tend to take a "take only memories, leave only footprints" approach to being online in general, so removing it was natural to me.

Comment: Welcome back! Best wishes.

Comment: Once again, welcome!

Answer (score 34):

My exact reaction was this:

"!!"

I am beyond excited to work with Slate again (having previously been co-mods on Literature). I'm well aware that she has excellent skills in the moderation / community management department, and really can't think of someone I would have been more excited to see take on this role. (Now I understand Philippe's cryptic hint in chat and Cat's cryptic note on Twitter...)

While I don't think I've interacted with Charlotte before, I'm sure she'll also be an excellent addition to the team.

Now, if you'll excuse me, I'm going to go jump up and down in excitement.

Comment: Your exact reaction was to pull grab a keyboard, hold shift, and press the ‘1’ key twice? Wierd... then again, this *is* meta :D

Comment: @EkadhSingh - I'd share a screenshot, but it happened in the Teachers' Lounge... ;)

Answer (score 23):

So incredibly excited to have the two of you join the team!  Welcome!

Answer (score 21):

Welcome Slate and Charlotte. I'm thrilled to see new additions to the CM team, and I hope you will be in for a fun ride. (hopefully the angry meta mob won't be too hard on you two)

I see you both talk about your previous experiences here on the network. When looking at both your profiles I only see 1 reputation scattered all over the place. Did you both make a conscious decision to start with a fresh account, or was this in some way mandated?

Comment: Not mandated -- I wanted a fresh start :)

Comment: As we say in Brazil "eu sou braba" not afraid of angry mobs. haha but thank you! And yeah, I have an older account that I have been using and I just wanted to have something new and fresh but we did not plan on doing it together, it was spontaneous.

Comment: Great to hear no-one pressured you into having new accounts :)

Comment: @Slate lame pun but can't help it: You start with a clean slate! *going to  hide in a corner* :D

Answer (score 15):

I won't be shy and so I'll follow the recent trend of welcoming the CM's in one of their native languages. Bem-vindas [welcome] Charlotte e [and] Slate Mulheres-Maravilha [Wonder Woman].

We naturally expect extraordinary feats from both. I'm especially glad Slate is interested in Literature which has us looking forward to some masterful writing.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Yeah, poor Slate... I have a feeling she's gonna get stuck doing a lot of ghost writing for me!  (Kidding, my mother - the English and creative writing teacher - would kill me.)

Answer (score 11):

Awesome! Congratulations to both of you, and I'm very happy to see some more CMs with so much SE experience!

As for Slate:

> "At her last job, her focus was in statistics and data science for spaceflight applications. She studied physics and math, and continues to self-study both in her free time."

As a mathematical physicist who did not know that about you before, that was an absolutely delightful piece of information to learn today!

> "She has been a community empowerer in the Brazilian tech community collaborating with tutorial videos, responding to questions over Twitter and email about how to start a career in tech, programming, or data management. She has a database technologist certification and experience handling relational databases."

In other words: she is a rockstar.

Comment: That safely sums it up.  We're incredibly lucky to have them both.  It was a very competitive pool and these two were top of the heap.

Answer (score 9):

Congrats @Charlotte and @Slate!  It'll be great to have you :)

Have fun!