# What are the criteria for becoming an employee of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team, company

I am new on this site and was reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367910/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associates-945-slate-and-948-charlotte?cb=1) question. First of all congratulations to user Slate and user Charlotte. I have some questions:

- **If someone wants to become a Stack Overflow staff member, how can they do so?**
- **What are the criteria for choosing a staff member?** How do other staff members decide whether someone else should become a staff member?
- **Just like for moderators, is there any reputation threshold or badges you need to have in order to become a staff member?**

I did some Google research as well as [a search on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=how%20can%20one%20become%20a%20stackexchange%20staff%20member), but I couldn't find the information.

Comment: How do you get a job _anywhere_?

Comment: By interview @jonrsharpe

Comment: There is your answer.

Comment: But where is the interview taken @Luuklag? And how can one register for interview?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here

Comment: Insanit......send them your CV/resume.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If someone wants to become Stack Overflow staff member how can they do so?

You get hired - you can find the [listings here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) for currently open jobs, apply, meet the criteria listed, do interviews and such.

In general, all other things considered, I'm told that a good cover letter is helpful, alongside a relevant resume. If someone in staff feels you're a good fit, you might also be able to get them to refer you.

> What are the criteria for choosing a staff member?

I've never gotten as far as 'serious' interviews. Apparently good cover letters help. Traditionally, knowing the platform well has been a key criteria and might be helpful. Many roles might not involve actually working with the community, so it depends

I suspect it would very much depend on the role and team, since SE does have a significant number of staff in sales, admin and other non public Q&A roles.

You can find a baseline expectation for those specific roles in the respective listings.

> Just like for mods, is there any reputation threshold or badges you need to have in order to become a staff member?

Generally no. We've historically had folks with not much reputation and badges come in and be *spectacular* members of staff. While I personally feel we need to hire 'in community' for some roles - it should never be a defining criteria. We've even at  one point had an entire sub team of community managers who were from outside the community and helped build up many of the sites that were started at the time.