# Getting Moderator Attention for Offensive Flags on Private Beta

Tags: support, flags, private-beta

On private beta I understand the team are moderators.
[Who is notifed when a post is flagged in a private beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59692/who-is-notifed-when-a-post-is-flagged-in-a-private-beta)

I also understand how an offensive flag is raised and handled.
[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

What I'd like to know, how does one get reasonably swift moderator attention for am offensive post in private beta, where there may not be many users online?

[image]

The comment is making fun of a question posted by a user with ESL (English as a Second Language), obviously not in the prefered hemisphere. Not on.

Comment: gather people who should flag

Comment: @Skippy, what post.... I'll be there in a minute

Comment: http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-come-we-have-such-a-strong-australian-contingent/266#266 @psubsee2003

Comment: young guys getting a little over the top with humor

Comment: side question: how did a private beta manage to get an offensive post?

Comment: @JanDvorak Meta joking going too far, it was not meant to be offensive, but is really inappropriate.. it will all be good.. not to worry.. enough on this topic, just wanted someone to step in before we had a bar room brawl

Comment: @JanDvorak it's borderline in terms of what we would normally call offensive and is from a higher rep user in the Private Beta, but if someone who was the target of the joke took offense (and I can understand why they would), it doesn't belong

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FvWnh.jpg

Comment: @Skippy is it so bad it warrants an automatic 100 rep penalty? If not, it's not offensive.

Comment: @Skippy I saw the ones that weren't deleted yet (not sure if there were more), but I flagged the comments.

Comment: @JanDvorak one of the comments is mocking someone's question and ethnicity, not to mention this is on a post that as a joke targets a group of people, as being let's say less than competent. It seriously is so off topic and targeting people on race/country. It can't have a place here. Trust me to be the one to see it and bring it to SMO.. LIke i need to be in the centre of any more trouble yikes O,O

Comment: if it's the image linked to by BoltClock'saUnicorn that's in question, I don't really find it offensive and I'd just let it slip.

Comment: @Skippy can you post a screenshot for us uninvinitiated?

Comment: I think 'immature' is the word you are looking for, 'young' doesn't necessarily apply. Aside from that, it may be beneficial to see if a CM is online at all, if something is that bad they should be able to help, though they are busy and not always available!

Comment: @JanDvorak bahahahaha NO that's the B Unicorns joke, nothing to do with it.. as if, I am watching STAR TREK as we speak hahahahahhaa

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: I was answering your side question with that image :) I can't see what's in the question as I'm not in the private beta.

Comment: oh... sorry :-)

Comment: @RhysW that is why I cane here, was trying to see if any were around looking at the posts

Comment: From the screenshot, I'd say the question is the offensive one here.

Comment: @Skippy the post is gone now (not sure if it was a self delete due to downvotes or not), but the bad part is you are the only person on the site who can still see it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 it is not me I'm worried about.. should I take ou the screen shot? The comment was a mock of how some user's with poor english have been posting questions.. not nice; the spam flags deleted it.. good job

Comment: @Skippy leave it... there are far worse on MSO.

Comment: and we're going so well on private,, it's a hiccup, they need to take that kind of humor to the pub.. or a chatroom called pub

Comment: @JanDvorak the question is off topic, but not offensive. It's over and doused and that's all that matters, overall the site is blossoming (with what I'm not sure!) ;) night, I'm off to bed (well morning)

Comment: @Skippy - Did you consider just asking the user to edit the post or remove it?  I don't see it as being so offensive as to warrant the user losing 100 reputation.

Comment: @jmort253  I originally flagged and wanted to stay anonymous, not creating a fuss, but the comment on the post, got me worried, and I am one person and wanted to get some moderation help, rather than lock horns with two other members on the site. I am one person and do not want to get involved with debate about what is offensive. As the post was, ultimately, flagged and marked as offensive, your opinion of it not being offensive is moot. In this interest of clarity I answered your ping, but really it's over and people seem ok. So I'd rather not rehash it further cheers

Comment: @Skippy - Makes sense. I can understand not wanting to get in the middle of a conflict. If it comes to conflicts or just flagging, flagging is always the better option. I just assume sometimes that people are going to play nice when we tell them things, but unfortunately that isn't always the case.....

Comment: @jmort253 in my case, I am trying to break old habits and wanting to do the right thing simultaneously.. I was really offended by the post and comment, and just wasn't the right person to deal with it, knowing how the system works, I didn't want it sitting there for a prolonged period and risking any more comments being posted, and the stakes getting higher in terms of any emotional incense.. if that makes sense. So, unfortunately, make it more public, by coming here, but I knew we'd find people with enough rep to deal with it. Our site is doing well overall, don't want to give the wrong idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't get very fast reaction times during the private beta. Only SE employees handle the flags at that point, so the delay will be usually higher than after the moderator appointments. But in my experience they usually check regularly enough that this is not a problem in most cases.

If there is a serious incident that requires a faster reaction, usually someone will notify SE. Typically a user that is already a moderator on another site will ping someone from SE in the mod-only chat to make them aware of the situation.

And as ChrisF mentioned, offensive posts can be handled by the community alone, if everyone does the correct thing and uses the offensive flags.

Comment: yup, it was just there was a post, I flagged, really out of line, then a comment, which was not going in the right direction.. Seriously out of line for a global community.. just younger guys getting carried away

Answer (score 6):

When a post reaches 6 offensive flags the system automatically deletes the post.

Therefore all you need to do is find five other users to flag the post as well and *poof* it'll disappear.

Use chat to gather reinforcements, or if all else fails and if the post is *really* offensive invite some other users into the beta for the express purpose of flagging.

Comment: 5 users on private beta :) that's why I am here, particularly when some users find it funny..

Comment: @Skippy - in that case send out some invites to other users who'll be more sympathetic. The additional problem this weekend is that the community team are all en-route to NYC.

Comment: Ah didn't know, would explain it.. when the cat's away and all that :)

Comment: Duh, the correct solution is to engage an employee who can then delete it with a single red flag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn that's what I'm trying to do ;) so how do I find one, we have 10,000 SMO ninjas here, there's got to be one or two hahaha

Comment: @Skippy, If there are a total of 5 users on this private beta, why is it so urgent to get this post deleted instantly?  I suspect the right answer is to flag it, take a deep breath, and let existing processes handle it.

Comment: @D.W. that was my original intention, then an inappropriate comment was posted under it, so I wanted to source a mod, rather than go into a head to head confrontation, as that's what would have happened at that time, as being Australian, with an Asian father, I was becoming increasingly upset, by the joke re people's poor English and I figured it may also offend others and didn't want it to become a big problem, o so it's here on SMO, but we're all happy again in our private beta.. I can here to find suitable mod.. savvy?

Comment: Oh and there's 170 user's but there were only a few floating around at that time and two of them were ok with the post.. do you think the posts are ok? @D.W. you need to translate it to fit your nationality... given we are trying to form a consensus in a new community, it's not really good to poke fun at different nationalities..